# Is there a way to quickly browse multiple pdfs in a directory?

Tags: pdf

I often generate directories full of PDFs. I want to quickly flip through them as though they are pictures.

Nautilus will create thumbnails of the PDFs that I can enlarge using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> but they never get large enough to see the detail that I want.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend `gnome-sushi`, it's in the [default repositories](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-sushi/) and works as you describe. After installing it, you just select the PDF in Nautilus and tap the space bar. Gnome-sushi will then display the PDF in a popup window at 100% zoom, which you can scroll through if you like.

The best thing is it also works on many other file types, so you can start playing a song, quick-preview an image, etc, with a tap of the space bar. Highly recommended for it's utility and one of those programs which I immediately install on any new machine.

Comment: This was my go-to method but there appears to be a bug at the moment:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-sushi/+bug/1644781

Comment: gnome-sushi is working again as of 19.10

Answer (score 8):

I like @Glutanimate answer since it uses a real pdf viewer. I have an alternative that allows viewing any list of files (including pdf) as a presentation, on fullscreen if needed:

**impressive**

- Install it

  > sudo apt-get install impressive
- Then, from a terminal in the directory containing your pdfs:

  > impressive -T0 -w *.pdf
- It will display a presentation of your pdf files.
  the -T0 option removes transitions (or, equivalently, -t None), and the -w wraps the presentation (you can return to 1st slide from the last one).

  You may want to use the -f switch to avoid starting in fullscreen mode (anyway you can toggle to fullscreen hitting the "f" key).

  For *zooming*, position your mouse where you want to zoom in, and hit "z".

Otherwise I am just discovering the **Zathura** pdf reader, it's highly customizable, I suspect there might be a way to write a plugin and bind keys to switch to the next pdf.

Comment: with gnome-sushi in a useless state, this is a really nice solution...  and maybe better than gnome-sushi in the end.

Comment: Thanks. This is very much impressive

Comment: How does one get this?  On my Ubuntu distro `sudo apt-get install impressive` returns `E: Unable to locate package impressive`.

Comment: @sh37211 impressive is not present in ubuntu 20.04 repositories, but in 22.04 it is. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=impressive

Answer (score 3):

If you don't manage to find a better solution you could give this script a try:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# NAME:         pdfwalker  
# AUTHOR:       (c) 2014 Glutanimate <https://github.com/Glutanimate/>
# DESCRIPTION:  Invoke one pdf file at a time
# DEPENDENCIES: mupdf
# LICENSE:      GNU GPLv3 (http://www.gnu.de/documents/gpl-3.0.en.html)        

############# Functions ###############

gui_notify(){
  notify-send -i application-pdf "PDF Walker" "$1"
  echo "$1"
}

arg_compose_filearray(){
    # recursively add pdf files and folders in given arguments to array
    unset Files
    FileCountCurrent="1"
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' File; do
        if [[ ! "$(file -ib "$File")" == *application/pdf* ]]
          then
              echo "Error: '$File' is not a pdf file. Ignoring."
              continue
        fi
        Files[FileCountCurrent++]="$File"
    done < <(find "$@" -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 | sort -z --version-sort)
    FileCountTotal="${#Files[@]}"
}

arg_check(){
  if [[ "$FileCountTotal" = "0" ]]; then
    gui_notify "ERROR: No PDF files found."
    echo "Exiting..."
    exit 1
  fi
}

############## Checks #################

arg_compose_filearray "$@"
arg_check

################ Main #################

FileCountCurrent="1"
for File in "${Files[@]}"; do
  echo "Opening file $FileCountCurrent of $FileCountTotal:"
  echo "$File"
  mupdf "$File" > /dev/null 2>&1
  ((FileCountCurrent++))
done

echo "Done."
```

**Installation**

Copy and paste the contents of the code box above into a new empty text file, save it, and mark the script as executable via the Properties menu of your file manager.

Make sure to install all dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install mupdf
```

**Usage**

```
pdfwalker <pdf files or directories>
```

For instance:

```
pdfwalker "~/Downloads/PDF" "~/Documents/Scans"
```

The script will recursively find all PDF files in the selected directories and open them one after another with `mupdf`. To switch to the next file in line, simply close the current `mupdf` window (<kbd>Q</kbd>). If you want to exit the script completely you can terminate it from the terminal via <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I tried some of the aforementioned solutions, but they did not work for me.

So I crafted this simple one-liner:

`find ./pdf-folder/ -iname '*\.pdf' | xargs -n1 mupdf`

It only requires `mupdf` (package `findutils` contains the `find` command is marked essential in Debian and Ubuntu)

Usage:

- Press `q` inside the mupdf viewer to get the next document
- Switch back to the terminal and press `Ctrl-C` to break the loop

Answer (score 0):

You could search through the terminal, using `grep` to look for whatever words you're interested in, as in

```
grep "word" *
```

should search all files in the current dir for `word`.

PDF's should have some text in them so this should work, maybe/maybe not run through `strings` then piped to `grep`, as in

```
strings -f * | grep "word"
```

unless the PDF's are all images.

---

Or, use an "e-library" program like [Calibre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/calibre/)

This screenshot looks promising: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the CLI file manager [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) worked best for me.

Install via `sudo apt install ranger`

I have it set up to preview PDFs as text. Here a sample screenshot:

[image]

But it will depend on your PDFs. Mine have little text (generated bills) and the text preview works very well and fast.

I can go from file to file with the arrow keys.